# How can I parse a string based on character count?

Tags: scala, databricks

I am trying to parse a string and append the results to a new fields in a dataframe?  In SQL, it would work like this.

```
UPDATE myDF
SET theyear = SUBSTRING(filename, 52, 4),
SET themonth = SUBSTRING(filename, 57, 2),
SET theday = SUBSTRING(filename, 60, 2),
SET thefile = SUBSTRING(filename, 71, 99)
```

I want to use Scala to do the work because the dataframes that I'm working with are really huge and using this will be magnitudes faster than using SQL to do the same.  So, based on my research, I think it would look something like this, but I don't know how to count the number of characters in a field.

Here is some sample data:

```
abc://path_to_all_files_in_data_lake/2018/10/27/Parent/CPPP1027.Mid.414.gz
```

I want to get the year, the month, the day, and the file name, so in this example, I want the dataframe to have this.

[image]

```
val modifiedDF = df
  .withColumn("theyear", )
  .withColumn("themonth", )
  .withColumn("theday", )
  .withColumn("thefile", )

modifiedDF.show(false)
```

So, I want to append four fields to a dataframe: theyear, themonth, theday, and thefile.  Then, do the parsing based on the count of characters in a string.  Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and expected results please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably rather use RegEx for pattern matching than string length.  In this simple example, I extract the main date pattern using `regexp_extract` then build the other columns from there using `substring`:

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq( ( "abc://path_to_all_files_in_data_lake/2018/10/27/Parent/CPPP1027.Mid.414.gz" ), ( "abc://path_to_all_files_in_data_lake/2019/02/28/Parent/CPPP77.Mid.303.gz" ) )
  .toDF("somePath")
  .withColumn("theDate", regexp_extract($"somePath", "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]", 0) )
  .withColumn("theYear", substring($"theDate", 1, 4 ) )
  .withColumn("theMonth", substring($"theDate", 6, 2 ) )
  .withColumn("theDay", substring($"theDate", 9, 2 ) )
  .withColumn("theFile", regexp_extract($"somePath", "[^/]+\\.gz", 0) )


df.show
```

My results:

[image: My results]

Does that work for you?

Comment: This should work!  But...how do I get the specific field from my own DF loaded into this thing?  I tried this: val dfMod = Seq(df.filename).  I got: value filename is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
val dfMod = Seq(df.filename).  My DF is simply named 'df' and the field named 'filepath' is the full path of the file.  These all actually have the same length of characters up to the file name, so if it's easier to do it by counting characters, maybe that's an option.

Comment: Do you still need help?  In my example, I'm using `Seq` to generate the test data.  If your dataframe already exists, you don't need to do this step.

Comment: I noticed that.  I don't need the Seq.  How can I read directly from a field in a dataframe?

Comment: Oh, I just figured it out!
val dfMod = df.select($"filepath")
Thanks so much for the help with this thing!!

Answer (score 0):

Using built in functions on data frame -
You can use `length(Column)` from `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` to find the size of the data in a column.

```
    val modifiedDF = df
      .withColumn("theyear", when(length($"columName"),??).otherwise(??))
```

Using Scala -

```
    df.map{row => 
      val c = row.getAs[String]("columnName")
      //length of c = c.length()
      //build all columns
      // return (column1,column2,,,)
    }.toDF("column1", "column2")
```

Comment: This might work!  But, how do I get the year from the field named 'filepath' inside the dataframe, which is literally named 'df'.  In Excel, I can get the year with this: =MID(A1,52,4)
So, A1 is the cell reference, I start 52 characters from the beginning, and I get 4 characters, which is 2019.  Thanks.

Comment: Using scala you can read file name in a variable using getAs then do substring operation on it. 
You can also use substring function on sql.functions package as shown by @wBob

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working solution!

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val dfMod = df
  .withColumn("thedate", regexp_extract($"filepath", "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]", 0) )
  .withColumn("theyear", substring($"thedate", 1, 4 ) )
  .withColumn("themonth", substring($"thedate", 6, 2 ) )
  .withColumn("theday", substring($"thedate", 9, 2 ) )
  .withColumn("thefile", regexp_extract($"filepath", "[^/]+\\.gz", 0) )


dfMod.show(false)
```

Thanks for the assist wBob!!!